# How to run Spring in Action Third Edition source code

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven-3

I extracted **sia3-code** ZIP file and imported the extracted **sia3-code** folder as **Existing Maven Projects** in my **Eclipse Helios IDE**. It imported just fine but I don't see any of the **src** folder in the build path and I can't run the test classes.

This is how it looks:
[image]

Could someone help me with how to get the source code that comes along with the book running as maven project?

Thanks.

Comment: For those looking for 4th edition: https://ericsprogrammingblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/import-and-run-spring-in-action-4th-edition-chapter01-in-intellij-idea/

Answer (score 3):

1] download the sourcecode into a dir, which i'll refer to as code_dir_tree

2] edit the pom.xml in the code_dir_tree root as follows:

replace:

```
<modules>
        <module>translators</module>
</modules>
```

with:

```
<modules>
        <module>knights</module>
    <module>rest-client</module>
    <module>springidol</module>
    <module>springidol-annotation</module>
    <module>springidol-aop</module>
    <module>springidol-aspectj</module>
    <module>springidol-atinject</module>
    <module>springidol-autodiscovery</module>
    <module>springidol-javaconfig</module>
    <module>springidol-qualifiers</module>
</modules>
```

3] from a command shell in the code_dir_tree root directory, run:  mvn eclipse:clean

4] within eclipse, ensure you have a refreshed, preferably empty workspace available

5] copy the entire code_dir_tree manually into the workspace - not the individual projects, the code_dir_tree itself.

6] in eclipse, perform import | existing maven projects, select the code_dir_tree root (already within the workspace),
    ensure all the projects including the pom.xml are selected, hit finish

7] run maven updates, clean install builds - all -maven- projects aside from rest-client, which has an unresolved dependency,
    should now be ready to go

*The remaining projects, spitter and SpringPizza, are gradle projects - STS, which has gradle integraton, needs to be installed to get these imported*

8] in eclipse, perform import | gradle project, select the spitter directory, hit ok, select 'build model', when complete ensure all are selected, hit finish

9] repeat the same process as in 8]  for SpringPizza

***That's it - you should be ready to roll!***

Answer (score 1):

In the package explorer, right-click on the java directory and select Build Path->Use as source folder.  Do this for both java directories (the one in src/main and the one in src/tst).

Then right click on the project and select Configure->Convert to Maven project.

**UPDATE:**

I think you need to install the M2Eclipse Plugin.  Here are [some directions](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/install-sect-marketplace.html).  Then you should be able to right click on your project and select Maven->Enable Dependency Management.

Since you are utilizing Spring, I would *highly* recommend you checkout SpringSource Tool Suite.  It's Eclipse bundled with a lot of useful plugins (such as m2eclipse).  Here's a brief snippet from their website:

> The Spring Tool Suite™ (STS) provides the best Eclipse-powered development environment for building Spring-powered enterprise applications. STS supplies tools for all of the latest enterprise Java and Spring, and comes on top of the latest Eclipse releases.

Read about STS and download it at its site: http://www.springsource.org/sts

**SECOND UPDATE:**

I think I see what you did wrong.  It looks like you specified the root of your project as the directory that contains the folder 'sia3-code'.  That caused all the projects to be collapsed under one big project, which, I'm pretty sure, is not the way you want to do it.

Remove the project from your Eclipse.  Then in the Package Explorer, right-click and select Import.  Select "Existing Projects into Workspace".  Select the root directory to be /your/path/to/sia3-code/ (do not select the root directory to be /your/path/to/).  Then select Finish.  You'll see that you have 10+ projects imported into your IDE.

The above steps were verified in STS, so you might need to adapt them a bit if you are using Eclipse Helios.

Comment: When I go to `src/test` or `src/main` folder, right click on it, select `Build Path`, it shows me `No actions available`. http://imageshack.us/a/img20/6672/sia3codeknights.png is the screenshot of what I am getting by doing what I explained above.

Comment: :Many thanks for the reply again.I actually already have `m2e` plugin installed already which is why I think I see `Maven->Disable Dependency Management` at the place of `Maven->Enable Dependency Management`. http://imageshack.us/a/img543/3296/sia3codem2e.png and http://imageshack.us/a/img829/7139/m2ef.jpg images show the state of my IDE.I think I wouldn't have been able to import the `sia3-code` as `Maven Project` otherwise.Yes, I've got `STS` downloaded.I wonder what I am missing.Do you think its the `gradle plugin` I am missing? I actually want to get it working first on Eclipse.

Comment: I've worked on some Maven Projects on the same IDE and maven-eclipse plugin always worked like a charm. I think The `sia2-code` uses `gradle` that I seem to be missing. I am not sure if thats all I am missing though. I would first like to get it running on eclipse.

Comment: thanks for the reply again. I tried that as well but I just wasnt able to get all the projects working. And I think Spitter is a `Gradle Project` so I dont think it could work without having Gradle Installed. Finally shifted to STS version 3. http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=47320&tstart=0 were some instructions given to get the sample app code from Sping in Action 3rd edition working. Unfortunately even on STS 3 I dint have the `1->b) Right click on spitter-web project, select Properties>Deployment Assembly` in the given instruction.